# Make og:title propercase Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, php, open-graph

**Issue**
My client has added their product titles in UPPERCASE, and as such the `og:title` property is also in uppercase.

For example: 'MY T SHIRT'

**Current Code**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getName())) ?>" />
```

**Desired Result**: I want the title to be output in Propercase.

For example: 'My T Shirt'

**Can anyone please suggest an update to the code to get this working as desired?**

Answer (score 1):

This issue isn't specific to Magento but can easily be fixed by using PHP's [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) function.

ucwords will capitalize the first letter of each word while making the rest of the letters lowercase.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->stripTags(ucwords($block->getProduct()->getName()))) ?>" />
```