# Change meta tile from uppercase to lowercase

Tags: magento2, meta-title

Good evening community,
I ask for help from you, because I am not an expert programmer.
I would need to change all meta tiles from uppercase to lowercase. Example :
MY PRODUCT
in
My product.
I think it is already possible from the magento back end by going to the Shop-> Configuration-> Catalog-> Auto-Generation
[image]product fields tab and add some attributes to the name field, but I have no idea which. So I'm waiting for someone more experienced than me to give me a hand. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no options available in the admin Auto-Generation product field options to change the case of any of the generated values including the Meta Title.

You can read more about how the auto generated product fields work here https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-fields-autogenerated.html

To change all your Meta Titles to lowercase is relatively simple to achieve but it does require to be programmed via a custom module.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I read this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256272/make-ogtitle-propercase-magento-2 where a user seems to have had the same need as me. But I don't understand the answer he got, if you need to go and modify some string inside some file or thing. I would like you to at least give me an example a little more detailed.